# Creating a site tour

Tags: 7

I created a site that allows people to create user accounts, login and communicate with other users, or view certain content. The site is completely finished accept for one thing. I am worried that users are going to get confused, or not know about all of the features that are on the site, so what I wanted to do, was to create a walk through tutorial of the site. I noticed there is a [module](http://drupal.org/project/site_tour) for Drupal 6 that looks like it does almost exactly what I am trying to do, but I can't seem to find anything similar for Drupal 7, and I was wondering if anyone else has had any better luck. Also, I am I don't want the tutorial there permanently. I want it only there for the first few times that the user logs in, and then after that, to simply have a link saying "take site tour" on the bottom. Does anyone know of a module that can do that?

Comment: As alternative solutions, you could create a screencast or use the advanced help module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Guiders-JS](http://drupal.org/project/Guiders-JS) module. It is a guide / walk-through for your site's pages.
The Guider can show the page parts and give a short explanation about each part's functionality and purpose. This module is for anyone who is looking for a walk-through, guide, intro, or just a sequenced messaging system.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to have the next button go to another page?

Comment: one thing I'm wondering, is how do I make it so that it only happens the first time the user logs in?

Comment: Honestly I have never used the module. Only knew about it. Your going to have to hit the module's issue queues for further help.

Answer (score 4):

This module can do the same: [Guidance](http://drupal.org/project/guidance)

For controlling first time, you can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Joyride JQuery for Drupal Site Tours](http://drupal.org/project/joyride) module for Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 ships with [Tour module](http://drupal.org/node/1921162)! :)